# Order by (Sorting) is very slow in neptune gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

We are using Amazon Neptune AWS graph database. When we apply order by it is taking too much time.

```
g.V().
  has("Persons","_id","xxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx").
  out("joinGroup").
  skip(0).
  limit(100).
  project("lastActivity").
    by(__.inE("activity").
          has("display","visible").
          order().
            by("_createdOn",desc).
          limit(1).valueMap())
```

I simple want to get last Chat and have saved a chat node with group node. Person can have groups and can chat

```
>  Neptune Gremlin Profile
>     
>     ===================
>     Neptune steps:
>     [
>         NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex) {
>             JoinGroupNode {
>                 PatternNode[(?1, <_id>, "xxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx", ?) . project ?1 .], {estimatedCardinality=1, indexTime=0, joinTime=0,
> numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=1}
>                 PatternNode[(?1, <~label>, ?2=<Persons>, <~>) . project ask .], {estimatedCardinality=1008, indexTime=0, joinTime=0,
> numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=1}
>                 PatternNode[(?1, ?5=<joinGroup>, ?3, ?6) . project ?1,?3 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?6) .], {estimatedCardinality=9566,
> indexTime=0, joinTime=0, numSearches=1}
>             }, finishers=[limit(100)], annotations={path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Vertex(?3):VertexStep],
> joinStats=true, optimizationTime=1, maxVarId=11, executionTime=901}
>         },
>         NeptuneTraverserConverterStep
>     ]
>     + not converted into Neptune steps: [ProjectStep([lastActivity],[[VertexStep(IN,[activity],edge),
> ProfileStep, NeptuneHasStep([display.eq(visible)]), ProfileStep,
> NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, OrderGlobalStep([[value(_createdOn),
> desc]]), ProfileStep, RangeGlobalStep(0,1), ProfileStep,
> PropertyMapStep(value), ProfileStep]])]
>     
>     WARNING: >> ProjectStep([lastActivity],[[VertexStep(IN,[activity],edge),
> ProfileStep, NeptuneHasStep([display.eq(visible)]), ProfileStep,
> NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, OrderGlobalStep([[value(_createdOn),
> desc]]), ProfileStep, RangeGlobalStep(0,1), ProfileStep,
> PropertyMapStep(value), ProfileStep]]) << (or one of its children) is
> not supported natively yet
>     
>     
>     Runtime (ms)
>     ============
>     Query Execution: 900.745
>     
>     Traversal Metrics
>     =================
>     Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
>     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex)                                         53          53           1.226     0.14
>     NeptuneTraverserConverterStep                                         53          53           0.604     0.07
>     ProjectStep([lastActivity],[[VertexStep(IN,[...                       53          53         897.957    99.80
>       VertexStep(IN,[activity],edge)                                   13671       13671          49.116
>       NeptuneHasStep([display.eq(visible)])                            12680       12680         439.631
>       OrderGlobalStep([[value(_createdOn), desc]])                        53          53         399.198
>       RangeGlobalStep(0,1)                                                53          53           0.231
>       PropertyMapStep(value)                                              53          53           7.728
>                                                 >TOTAL                     -           -         899.788        -
>     
>     Predicates
>     ==========
>     # of predicates: 403
>     
>     Results
>     =======
>     Count: 53
>     
>     Index Operations
>     ================
>     Query execution:
>         # of statement index ops: 26460
>         # of unique statement index ops: 26460
>         Duplication ratio: 1.0
>         # of terms materialized: 0
```

Comment: I noticed that your question has not received any answers. Perhaps by now you have resolved your issue. In case not a few thoughts. It looks like the query is taking 900ms to run. The amount of time taken will depend on the amount of data that has to be touched. Have you tried doing the `inE` traversal and the `order` before the `project` step? This may allow the optimizer to do more.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. We just moved to mongodb. May be in our use case graph database did not fit best. Using indexes on mongodb. the query is running in 2-3 ms that was running on graph database 900ms.